# Count rows and sum r

Tags: r

I want to sum data by date but I don't know how to do this.

My data looks like

```
    date      LIKE  LOVE  WOW HAHA SAD  ANGRY
1 2016-02-25   949    0   3    0   0     2
2 2016-02-25 12653   14   0    0   1     0
3 2016-02-24  2981    0   7    3   10     0
4 2016-02-24  2500    6   0    3   0     5
```

My proposal is

```
    date      LIKE  LOVE  WOW HAHA SAD  ANGRY
1 2016-02-25 13602   14   3    0   1     2
2 2016-02-24  5481    6   7    6   10    5
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

---

Or `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~date, df1, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: @James Do you have `plyr` library loaded as well.  In that case, `dplyr::summarise_each(funs(sum))` should be needed